# Return range of numbers given number/step at with Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, logic

I am trying to generate this dynamically according of a number of slide/step.
Not sure what is the best way to accomplish with javascript:

Thanks!!

```
if(this.currentSlide == 1) return '1-12'
if(this.currentSlide == 2) return '13-24'
if(this.currentSlide == 3) return '25-36'
if(this.currentSlide == 4) return '37-48'
if(this.currentSlide == 5) return '49-60'
if(this.currentSlide == 6) return '71-82'
if(this.currentSlide == 7) return '83-94'
if(this.currentSlide == 8) return '95-106'
if(this.currentSlide == 9) return '107-118'
if(this.currentSlide == 10) return '119-130'
if(this.currentSlide == 11) return '131-142'
...
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually it was quite easy:

```
  data() {
    return {
      currentSlide: 1,
    }
  },

  getSlidesRange(curr) {
    const range = 12
    let maxRange = curr * range 
    let minRange = maxRange - (range - 1)
    return minRange.toString() + "-" + maxRange.toString();
  },

  let curr_range = this.getSlidesRange(this.currentSlide);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to find the pattern and create a function, example:

```
function myFunction(currentSlide) {
    return ((currentSlide - 1) * 12 + 1).toString() + "-" + ((currentSlide) * 12).toString();
}
```

This function is not valid for all your output pattern, but think about it and try to find one. Your approach of listing each possibility should be a last resort, since it is not practical.